# Remount filesystem to rw after running fsck on root without reboot

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning, mount, fsck

I think there's some issue with my harddrive. I face the read-only mode issue frequently. I usually run `fsck -y /dev/sda4` (my root is mounted on sda4) followed by `reboot`. The problem is it takes a long time for the system to reboot. I tried to remount the system using `sudo mount -o rw,remount /` but I'm getting the following error `mount: /: cannot remount /dev/sda4 read-write, is write-protected.` Is there any way I can convert my file system back to rw without reboot?

I use Ubuntu 18.04.

Edit: Added the screenshots from SMART Data of Disks utility.

[Part1 of SMART Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgpEr.png) [Part2 of SMART Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgGQq.png)

Edit: Updated SMART Data screenshots.

[SMART Attributes1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwfAc.png) [SMART Attributes2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyxVJ.png)

Comment: Have you checked the health of your drive?  eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  (I would run from a 'live' system such as Ubuntu install media, and if you're not familiar with `smartctl` results (rather verbose facts) using a `gnome-disk-utility` maybe easier to understand.

Comment: Do you also have Windows installed? If so, have you installed any Windows drivers that allow you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Is this SSD or HDD? Lastly, edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` application `SMART Data` window. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema also have windows installed on my pc. I dont have any drivers to acces linux file system from windows. Both are on HDD. And lastly I need some help to find the Disks application. Thank you for your patience! :D

Comment: The `Disks` application can be called from the normal "Super" key overview, just like any other app that you'd start. On 18.xx systems, your can't run fsck, as the disk is already mounted r/w, and has open files on it now. I'll put together an answer for you to show you how to properly run fsck on 18.xx systems.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying that too. Don't know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fsck**

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda4`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**bad blocking**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
         read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
         inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
         scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
         running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: I usually run the fsck on the terminal itself when my file system goes into read-only mode. I just want to resume working on my pc without a reboot. Is that possible cuz my system frequently goes into read-only mode.

Comment: @blazingeagle  In looking at the SMART data, you've got some bad blocks causing your problem. fsck must be run offline. Run it first. I've added the procedure for scanning your disk for bad blocks. Follow the instructions closely. Report back.

Comment: @blazingeagle Did you do the bad blocking yet?

Comment: I don't have an external drive to create an Ubuntu Live Usb. Due to the lockdown in my area, it's even difficult to get one. Can you please suggest some other alternative?

Comment: @blazingeagle If you can burn DVDs, that's the only other way.

Comment: I have used smart tools to fix the corrupted sectors. I have edited the question and added the screenshots of current smart data. Can you take a look and check if everything is fine?

Comment: @blazingeagle The updated SMART Data screenshots look fine. How did you use smarttools to fix the ton of sectors (instead of the bad blocking procedure that I gave you)?

Comment: I first ran a long SMART scan which gave me the LBA of first error. Then I divided it by 8 and ```sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda conv=sync bs=4096 count=1 seek=lba/8``` This step removed at least 8 bad sectors each time. Then I  kept running a select scan from the previously found error lba and repeated the ```dd``` process.

Comment: I found that method from some link online. Is my system fine after this?

Comment: @blazingeagle "*Is my system fine after this?*"... probably not. You zeroed 8 sectors at a time. You probably lost data that way. Why didn't you use the proper way indicated in my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106431/discussion-between-blazingeagle-and-heynnema).